# Get traffic data

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, bing-maps, azure-maps

Are there any public APIs or reference documentation which provide real-time traffic data (number of vehicles, road congestion's/blocks etc...) between 2 points? I have researched in Google Maps API and several other APIs which provide traffic data(MapQuest, Bing Maps, TomTom etc...) but they don't how the data is being represented on maps. Any help to this would be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: do you have any use-case for this? why would you need the number of vehicles in traffic? this could be a dangerous information to share publicly. this is just like letting everybody know the current population in a certain area in a certain moment. this information can be used in a bad way. i doubt api's would share this kind of information.

Comment: @tomjosef, car count data is publicly accessible data and has been for decades.

Comment: I have got the solution which can be extended as per need, have a look at it. https://developer.here.com/documentation#traffic

Answer (score 1):

Some departments of transportation have services that provide car counts, but these would be limited to their area of focus and likely only available in a hand full of places. Traffic data is not based on car count information alone. A lot of higher resolution traffic data uses other signals to measure traffic more accurately.

Take a look at Azure Maps. All the traffic data they provide in their map controls is also available as data in a REST service, even the data used to generate the traffic flow maps. Here is some useful links:

Traffic REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/traffic

Getting Started with Azure Maps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-manage-account-keys

Comment: Yes, I will have look on it. But I would like to explore the data shown on the **Traffic layers** of the **maps** which can be a hypothetical data like no. of vehicles traveled, incidents happened with their information, congestions/blocks etc. these data got can be a Historical or Real-Time(Live).

Comment: The Traffic API in Azure Maps provides incidents/road blocks, as well as flow data in raw form (Traffic Flow Segment API). A lot of traffic data out there is not based on car count as that is not the most accurate way to measure the flow of traffic.

Comment: I have got the alternate solution for my problem [link](https://developer.here.com/documentation#traffic). Having done the research on the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/traffic) it provides the traffic data too but not to the extent which is intended. *Thank You* for providing the source.

Comment: Azure Maps now provides access to raw traffic data, take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58661346/how-to-get-raw-traffic-flow-data

Comment: May I know how much data I can get means is it possible to get data for two years day per day and hour per hour ?

Comment: Currently only real time traffic data is available, not historical. Historical traffic data is something we are looking into potentially providing in the future.