# How to get raw traffic flow data

Tags: google-maps, maps, bing-maps, azure-maps

Creating application to use car count data from traffic.  How do I access the live google maps, waze or bing maps data?

Comment: I'm not sure anyone of those services is counting cars on all streets in any area. Or even most streets.

Comment: I really just need traffic data.  Speed and density

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Azure Maps platform has raw traffic data you can access for analysis purposes (I have been working with several others who are doing this).

There are two approaches. The first is to use the Traffic flow segment API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/traffic/gettrafficflowsegment

The second is to use the traffic flow tiles. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/traffic/gettrafficflowtile If you need traffic data over a large area, this is the lost cost approach, although more complex. Azure Maps provides the traffic flow tiles in both image (raster) like most platforms, but also in vector tile format (aligns with the open vector tile standard created by Mapbox). You can download all the tiles over your area of interest and extract the data for analysis. If you request traffic relative to the speed limit, each line segment in the tile will have a value between 0 and 1 which indicates the speed relative to the speed limit. For example, 0.2 would mean traffic is flowing at 20% of the speed limit.

Comment: Yes. It works in all countries Azure Maps has traffic flow data. Coverage documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/traffic-coverage

Comment: it is possible to get data for sevral days or only one day

Comment: Currently only real time traffic data is available, not historical. Historical traffic data is something we are looking into potentially providing in the future.

Comment: Please you do not know a way how can I get this dataset ? even via scraping a web site or not?

Comment: Many departments of transportation and cities make historical traffic data for available. You just have to go digging for it. Here is a couple https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=historical+traffic&sort=score+desc%2C+name+asc&as_sfid=AAAAAAWYYsMx1Bb2db3p3mX15bgaduX_-zZv3w0UpkOh25P5YIkAnEs5FhR7XogrAweyfGtxpx0V3-y_g8W-W3c6fadIqIke1qUfPOBCrLtCn9_lA9HLygTBYa0ah3X_VBjqkYA%3D&as_fid=af42051710140b43aeea4035944da12039bf58d3

Comment: Note that traffic data from commercial companies generally has a lot of restrictions around what you can do with it. Scraping and creating your own historical data often is against the terms of use of these platforms. That said, Azure Maps does allow caching of data for up to 6 months. So you could collect traffic data for an area of interest for a period of time, then use that as a sample data set for experimenting with.